# непонятная ошибка на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for,session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re

app = Flask(__name__)

messages = []
app.secret_key = '1234'

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'my_username'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'my_password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'geeklogin'

mysql = MySQL(app)
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s AND password = % s', (username, password, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        print(account)
        if account:
            session['login'] = True
            session['id'] = account['id']
            session['username'] = account['username']
            msg = 'Logged in successfully !'
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect username / password !'
    return render_template('login.html', msg = msg)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('loggedin', None)
    session.pop('id', None)
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/register', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form :
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s', (username, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            msg = 'Account already exists !'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'Invalid email address !'
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
            msg = 'Username must contain only characters and numbers !'
        elif not username or not password or not email:
            msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, % s, % s, % s)', (username, password, email, ))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered !'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
    return render_template('register.html', msg = msg)
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', messages=messages)

@app.route('/send', methods=['POST'])
def send():

    message = request.form['message']
    messages.append(message)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=4545)
```

код человек пытается пройти вход жалуется на `cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)` на моём компьютере код работает исправно
вот ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/adites9/mysite/flask_app.py", line 24, in login
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: @insolor я добавил ошибку

Comment: Это только трэйсбэк ошибки, добавьте сам текст ошибки, то что написано ниже трейсбэка.

Comment: Да уж, трейс обрывается на самом интересном месте.

Comment: А база на pythonanywhere настроена?

Comment: @insolor там всё настроено

Comment: Запуск настроен через вкладку Web или просто скрипт запускаете? На вкладке web в Log files в логах что-то есть кроме этой ошибки?

Comment: есть толька эта ошибка

Comment: Вот это похоже на ваш случай: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52780189/4752653, пробуйте делать как в конце ответа написано

Comment: Хотя как-то странно, по идее у вас как раз все в контексте запроса выполняется, не понятно почему connection пустой

Comment: всё равно ошибка